# Как получить вложения

Tags: json, swift, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, mvp

Работаю с API ВКонтакте, используя JSON в качестве формата данных, архитектурный паттерн MVP и Codable для парсинга JSON. Я получил данные в виде байтов и преобразовал их в строку, но как мне эту строку преобразовать обратно в Data без использования протоколов, чтобы при этом сохранился текст? Мой код выглядит так:

```
class NetManager {



    //Метод указывает, какие символы можно использовать в запросе
    private func makeRequest(urlString: String) -> URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        return urlRequest
    }

   //В этом методе  парсятся данные, полученные с сервера
    private func completionHandler(success: @escaping([Post]) -> Void, failure: (Int) -> Void, data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        //Если во время передачи данных с сервера произошла ошибка, то мы выводим ее здесь
        if error != nil {

            failure((error! as NSError).code)

        }

        else if data != nil {

            let jsonResponse = JSON(data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let posts = self.makeNewPosts(json: jsonResponse)
                    success(posts)

            }


        }
        else {

            failure(666)
        }

    }

//А здесь делается запрос к серверу и отображаются распарсенные данные
    func getMusic(success: @escaping([Post]) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {

        let urlString = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get.json?owner_id=-1212665&count&access_token=56dd06caf249416d3da146aae389e2d225ec807e69ba91170143fd43b747ed2bfe6702b568f711670eef8&v=5.71"

        let request = makeRequest(urlString: urlString)
        //Делаем запрос к серверу, получаем данные, добавляем их в completionHandler, где проверяем на ошибку
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {[weak self] data, response, error
            in

            self?.completionHandler(success: success, failure: failure, data: data, response: response, error: error)

        }

        task.resume()

    }

}


extension NetManager {
 //Если убрать декодирование вложений, которое я написал, то здесь мы преобразуем данные, полученные с сервера, в нужный нам формат и добавляем их в посты
    private func makeNewPosts(json: JSON) -> [Post] {
        var posts: [Post] = []
 var attachments: [Attachment] = []

        let itemsArray = json["response"]["items"].arrayValue

        for item in itemsArray {


 let text = item["text"].stringValue

let intValueOfDate = item["date"].int64Value
            let date = MyDateFormatter.getDateByStringFormatter(intValueOfDate)




            do {
let jsonData = try json.rawData

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                let result = try  decoder.decode([Attachment].self, from: jsonData)
                print(result)

           attachments = result
                for attachment in attachments{
                    if let song = attachment.audio, let postPhoto = attachment.photo
                    {
                        let picture = postPhoto.photo75

                        print("Song is: \(song.title), it's author is: \(song.artist), it lasts for: \(song.duration) minutes && seconds. You could download it on \(song.url). Image is: \(picture)")
                    }

                }

            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                }



            let post = Post(text: text, date: date, attachments: attachments)

            posts.append(post)

            }
        return posts
    }

}
```

---

```
 При выполнении кода я получаю ошибку "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format".
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить данные вложений в виде текста, нужно:

1. Назначить Photo и Audio реализаторами протокола Codable.
2. Убрать do-catch блок в методе makeNewPosts.
3. Теперь, после того, как мы убрали вышеупомянутый блок и реализовали протокол Codable в наших классах, нужно получить значения attachments с сервера.  Для этого нужно воспользоваться SwiftyJSON. Получаем доступ к массиву attachments с помощью .arrayValue, затем проходимся по элементам массива, используя типы, имеющиеся в SwiftyJSON(int/intValue, string/stringValue, в зависимости от того, опционально значение или нет. Хотя, начиная со Swift 5, в словарях, извлекаемых из JSON, значения являются опциональными, поэтому там string не используется).